# LaunchDarkly turn off for certain environments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, launchdarkly, feature-flags

I'm using the React SDK for LaunchDarkly and I need to initialize it just for certain environments. For example I need to skip LaunchDarkly initialization for localrun. Is there a way to do it?

This is the way I initialize it:

```
export default withLDProvider({
  clientSideID: config.launchDarkly.envId',
  options: {
    streamUrl: `https://clientstream-${config.launchDarkly.domain}`,
    baseUrl: `https://app-${config.launchDarkly.domain}`,
    eventsUrl: `https://events-${config.launchDarkly.domain}`,
  },
})(App);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `envId` to undefined for local and only set it accordingly in higher environments

Comment: envId doedn't accept undefined or null

Comment: i meant `clientSideID`.. apologies for the confusion.. i tested by setting `clientSideID` null locally.. works just fine..